# Kable group_rows not working

Tags: r, latex, knitr, kableextra

I'm trying to use `knitr::kable` in order to build a nice-looking table with several levels of grouping.  I've been successful with most of my work but I need to define several groups of rows and I thought that the function `kableExtra::group_rows` was exactly what I would need.  There is some pretty good documentation out there (https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) with some easy-to-follow examples regarding the use of this function, but I seem unable to reproduce the output being shown.

Here's the code snippet  [from the above linked documentation demonstrating the use of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OBUof.png).

However, the exact same code in my interactive session does not group the rows:

```
kable(mtcars[1:10, 1:6], caption = "Group Rows", booktabs = T) %>%
kable_styling() %>%
group_rows("Group 1", 4, 7) %>%
group_rows("Group 2", 8, 10)

|                  |  mpg| cyl|  disp|  hp| drat|    wt|
|:-----------------|----:|---:|-----:|---:|----:|-----:|
|Mazda RX4         | 21.0|   6| 160.0| 110| 3.90| 2.620|
|Mazda RX4 Wag     | 21.0|   6| 160.0| 110| 3.90| 2.875|
|Datsun 710        | 22.8|   4| 108.0|  93| 3.85| 2.320|
|Hornet 4 Drive    | 21.4|   6| 258.0| 110| 3.08| 3.215|
|Hornet Sportabout | 18.7|   8| 360.0| 175| 3.15| 3.440|
|Valiant           | 18.1|   6| 225.0| 105| 2.76| 3.460|
|Duster 360        | 14.3|   8| 360.0| 245| 3.21| 3.570|
|Merc 240D         | 24.4|   4| 146.7|  62| 3.69| 3.190|
|Merc 230          | 22.8|   4| 140.8|  95| 3.92| 3.150|
|Merc 280          | 19.2|   6| 167.6| 123| 3.92| 3.440|
```

As far as I can tell, the `group_rows` functions are completely ignored.  I've tried this by using the `format = "latex"` option to produce the raw latex and this has been similarly unsuccessful.  I'm starting to wonder if this function isn't deprecated?  A similar question saw some issues using it with special escape characters but I don't seem to be able to make it work even with simple data.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in that documentation, you need to specify `format = "latex"` in the `kable` function. Or you may choose to specify the format using the global option. Either way, the code should work.

For your example here,

```
kable(mtcars[1:10, 1:6], "latex", caption = "Group Rows", booktabs = T) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "hold_position") %>%
  group_rows("Group 1", 4, 7) %>%
  group_rows("Group 2", 8, 10)
```

I'm adding "hold_position" to pin the table with the code. It's optional.